# Why I can't make a two dimensional array with this code?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to solve a problem but I encounter a problem.

When I do this:

```
arr=[[[0]*5]*5]
```

I get this:

```
[[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]]
```

But when I try to select an element:

```
arr[0][0]
```

It returns this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why?

Comment: Maybe this is an important note: you aren't encountering an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove the outer `[]`:

```
arr=[[0]*5]*5
```

However that's a bad way to create nested lists. It's better to use:

```
arr = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
```

That way you don't get bitten by the ["shared reference problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/5393381).

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [[0]*5]*5 #will work
```

so `arr = [[[0]*5]*5]` is equivalent to `arr = [your required arr]` inside another list

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra pair of square brackets. Try `arr = [[0]*5]*5`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra pair of brackets.

Try instead:

```
arr = [[0] * 5] * 5
```

---

We can prove this by breaking down your code:

```
arr= [ [ [ 0 ] * 5 ] * 5]
```

We condense the innermost layer to be: `arr = [ [ [0]*5 ] * 5]` which returns:

```
[ [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] * 5]
```

Now the inner portion returns:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

As your desired result is now present, we now see that the remaining brackets are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

because you're not getting

```
[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

you're getting

```
[[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]]
```

omit the extra brackets.

```
arr=[[0]*5]*5
```